# prove: there exists surjection of N onto S = there exists an injection of S into N

Tags: analysis

> The following statements are equivalent: (a) $S$ is a countable set. (b) There exists a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$. (c) There exists an injection of $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$
>
> *Proof $(b)\implies(c)$*: If $H$ is a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$, we define $H_1:S\to \mathbb{N}$ by letting $H_1(s)$ be the least element in the set $H^{-1}(s)$:={$n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ : $H(n)$=$s$}. To see that $H_1$ is an injection of  $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$, note that if $s$,$t$ $\in$ $S$ and $n_{st}:=H_1(s)=H_1(t)$.

My question is:

> What is the meaning of " $H_1(s)$ be the least element in the set $H^{-1}(s)$:={$n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ : $H(n)$=$s$}."  And how could this " $H_1$ is an injection of  $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$" be derived?

Comment: Can you explain which parts make sense and which parts are unclear?

Comment: Is this $H^{-1}(s)$ the same as  $H_1(s)$ ?  $H^{-1}(s)$ is the inverse function of $H(n)$, so $H^{-1}(s)$ and  $H_1(s)$ have the same domain $s$ ?

Comment: And what's $H(n)=s$ ?Can someone make an example of this set $H^{-1}(s)$ ?

Comment: The notation $H^{-1}(s)$ is ambiguous. If $H$ is an invertible function (an injection and a bijection) then it denotes the inverse function like you say. In other contexts $H^{-1}(s)$ denotes the preimage of the function at $s$. That is, the set of elements $n$ such that $H(n)=s$.

Comment: Since you only know that $H$ is a surjection, it is not possible to assume that $H$ has an inverse, because if it is invertible, it must also be an injection.

Comment: $H^{-1}(s)$ here is the subset of $\mathbb N$ whose elements are mapped to the particular value $s$, in @JoshuaTilley's words  the preimage of the function at $s$.  $H^{-1}$ is a function from $S$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.  $H^{-1}(s)$ is never empty when $H$ is a surjection, and it then has a smallest element since  $\mathbb N$ is naturally well-ordered.  $H_1$ is then a function from $S$ to $\mathbb N$, meaning it is not the same as  $H^{-1}$. If $H$ is a surjection then  $H_1(s)$ must be an injection as $H_1(s) \cap H^{-1}(s')=\emptyset$ when $s \not = s'$

Comment: $$
\begin{matrix}  N & S  \\
1 & a_1  \\
2 & a_2 \\
3 & a_3 \\
.  &  .     \\   .  &  .     \\   .  &  .     \\  n  &  a_n     \\   n+1  &        \\    .   &        \\ 
  .   &        \\ \end{matrix}$$    Let's say $S$ is finite, How could $H_1(s)$ be the least? Like if $a_1$ maps to preimage 1 and 2,  then 1 is the least?

Comment: @Henry  Thank you

Comment: @Joshua Tilley   Thank you..

Comment: Picture $H$ by arrows from $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to $H(n)\in S$. We want to define $H_1:S\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by reversing the direction of the arrows so that $H(n)=s$ implies $H_1(s)=n$, but we can't do this because there may be more than one arrow pointing to $s$ which would make it ambiguous which arrow we should reverse. So, we arbitrarily choose one: we choose the arrow with the smallest $n$ at its base and $s$ at its tip, and reverse it i.e. define $H_1(s)=n$.